# Getting co-ordinates through SIM868 Gsm/Gprs/Gnss/Bluetooth Hat With Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gps

Hi Guys this is more a 3 part question. Im trying to build a GPS tracker that sends the data to a web server so we can display multiple vehicles at once.

Hardware:

GPS Unit = https://www.pishop.co.za/store/gsmgprsgnssbluetooth-hat-for-raspberry-pi?keyword=GSM&category_id=0
-PI unit = https://www.pishop.co.za/store/raspberry-pi-boards/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-plus

I have followed https://www.rhydolabz.com/wiki/?p=18639 which contains the code to use

but seem to be getting a error on line 50 for getting the co-ordinates

Answer (score 0):

That code is for python2, not python3 and `&gt` is nothing but `>` operator in python2.

Change all `&gt` -> `>` and `&lt` -> `<`

Comment: Even if you have identified the problem, it is expected that you provide a minimal working code. Please go through [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).